# VueJS show button when a value is not null

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I am very new to using VueJS and was wondering if there is a way to only show a button (that contains a slot) to only show if there is a button value given to the slot.

I'm using BootstrapVue Modals and the code is as follows:

I was not able to successfully get the modal running in the snippet but a screenshot of the opened modal is below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="//unpkg.com/babel-polyfill@latest/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <b-btn @click="showModal" class="modalBtn">
      <slot name="modalOpenBtn">Open Me</slot>
    </b-btn>

    <b-modal ref="myModalRef" hide-header no-fade hide-backdrop>
      <h1 class="font-18 text-black font-weight-bold mb-5">Merchant Closed</h1>
            <p class="font-14 text-black mb-20">please be aware that the merchant that you are viewing is currently closed. Feel free to add items to your cart but you will not be able to place your order until they’re open.</p>

      <div slot="modal-footer" class="w-100 d-flex align-items-center">
        <b-btn class="btn btn-teal btn-block font-14 w-100" block @click="hideModal">
          <slot name="modalCloseBtn">btn 1</slot>
        </b-btn>

        <b-btn class="btn btn-teal btn-block font-14 w-100" block @click="hideModal">
          <slot name="modalOkBtn">btn 2</slot>
        </b-btn>
      </div>
    </b-modal>
  </div>

  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      components: { App },
      methods: {
        showModal () {
          this.$refs.myModalRef.show()
        },
        hideModal () {
          this.$refs.myModalRef.hide()
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: Opened Modal Screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

You can conditonally render any element with Vues `v-if` directive:

```
// generic
<button v-if="myBooleanCondition">...</button>

// exmaple
<button v-if="something == true">...</button>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html